# Testing an a observable subject from a backend service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, rxjs-observables

I decided that I needed to improve my Angular app by actually testing the code before it got deployed. I have a C#/.Net background and I know my way around unit testing in that context.

Most of the unit tests I've written so far for my Angular app have been relatively straightforward, but testing an observable subject has become a stumbling block.

The code I'm writing tests for, consists of the following:

- A service that fetches news items (JSON) from a .Net App running in Azure
- A component that uses the above

The service retrieves news items using an HTTP GET request and updates an observable subject, the component subscribes to the subject and processes the JSON as it is offered by the subject.

The issue that I run into is testing the function that subscribes to the subject from the service and hands off the processing to another function.

Here's the code for the service:

```
export class NewsService {

  userObject!: UserSettings;
  localeId = 'da';
  data: any;

  public newsFeed!: News[];
  public newsFeedSubject = new Subject<any>();
  public newsFeedTimer = new Subscription();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    this.newsFeedTimer = this.timerSubscription();
    console.log('constructor called');
  }

  public timerSubscription(): Subscription {
    return timer(globalConstants.interval10Secs, globalConstants.interval2Hours).subscribe(() => {
      this.updateNewsFeedsSubject();
    });
  }

  public updateNewsFeedsSubject(): void {
    console.log(`Calling newsfeed service`);

    this.getNewsFeed(this.localeId).subscribe(newsFeed => {
      this.newsFeedSubject.next(newsFeed);

      console.log('NewsFeedTimer updated, newsfeed updated');
    });
  }

  public getNewsFeed(locale: string): Observable<News[]> {
    return this.http.get<News[]>(`${environment.baseURL}/${environment.newsServiceUrl}?locale=${this.localeId}`).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('NewsFeed Items retrieved: ', data)),
      tap(() => console.log('getNewsFeed: HTTP Request executed'))
    );
  }
}
```

and here's the code for the component:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  // Newsfeed service
  public newsFeed!: News[];

  constructor(private newsFeedService: NewsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.newsFeedServiceSubscribe();
  }

  public newsFeedServiceSubscribe(): void {
    this.newsFeedService.newsFeedSubject.subscribe(newsFeed => {
      this.updateNewsFeed(newsFeed);
      console.log('newsFeedServiceSubscribe function has been called');
    });
  }

  public updateNewsFeed(newsFeed: any): void {
    this.newsFeed = newsFeed;
    console.log('updateNewsFeed function has been called');
    console.log(newsFeed);
  }
}
```

And finally my (probably botched) attempt to test the newsFeedServiceSubscribe function:

```
  it('#newsFeedServiceSubscribe should call on the subscribe function on the updateNewsFeed subject', fakeAsync(() => {
    const spyNewsFeedSubjectSubj = spyOn(newsService.newsFeedSubject, 'subscribe');    
    spyOn(component, 'updateNewsFeed');
    
    expect(spyNewsFeedSubjectSubj.calls.any()).toBe(false,'subject should not have been called');
    expect(component.updateNewsFeed).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);

    component.newsFeedServiceSubscribe();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    
    newsService.newsFeedSubject.next(mockNewsfeedTestData);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(spyNewsFeedSubjectSubj.calls.any()).toBe(true,'subject should have been called');
    expect(component.updateNewsFeed).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  }));
```

The actual code runs just fine the news items are "returned" from the subject and processed just fine, but I just can't seem to get the test right. I would be expecting that the subject (in the service) is updated when I call the "next" method on the subject and I would then expect the subscription in the newsFeedServiceSubscribe function to actually call the updateNewsFeed function in the component.

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. How do I actually test that the subscription on the subject returns data and the updateNewsFeed is called?

Thanks,
Bjarne

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the whole spec file, it's hard to tell how you're getting the instance of the `NewsService`.  My guess is the `NewsService` used in the spec might not be the same instance as the one injected into the `HomeComponent`

With a `beforeEach` you can get the instance of the `NewsService` from the `TestBed`.

```js
let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
let newsService: NewsService;
let component: AppComponent;

const mockNewsfeedTestData: any = [];
  
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;

  // Get instance of NewsService
  // Newer Angular versions use TestBed.inject
  newsService = TestBed.get(NewsService);
});
```

Then the test case would be something like....

```js
it("#newsFeedServiceSubscribe should call on the subscribe function on the updateNewsFeed subject", fakeAsync(() => {
  spyOn(component, "updateNewsFeed");

  component.newsFeedServiceSubscribe();
  newsService.newsFeedSubject.next(mockNewsfeedTestData);

  expect(component.updateNewsFeed).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
}));
```

A stackblitz of working example from the code you provided...

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/unit-test-subsribe-01?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simpler way. In your component.spec file, simply create a mock-service and return mock-data and then run the test for that. something like this:

```
// In your component.spec file, 

@Injectable()
class MockService extends RealService {
  yourOriginalServiceMethod() {
    return of(mockData);
    // Here mockData can be any mocked-data. It should be of whatever the type your 
       original method in the service returns. Like an object 
   // 'of' is the RXJS operator. It will turn your mockData to an Observable so that when you run the test case, it will be subscribed without any issue. 
  }
}
  
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;

  realService = TestBed.get(RealService); // this is important to test the subscription error scenario
});

describe('AppComponent', () => { // 2
  beforeEach(async(() => { // 3
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        {
           provide: MockService,
           useClass: RealService
        }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

// Now your test case, fakeAsync or async - nothing is required.  

it("component #newsFeedServiceSubscribe() method for successful subscription",() => {
  spyOn(component, "newsFeedServiceSubscribe").and.callThrough();
  component.newsFeedServiceSubscribe();
  expect(component.updateNewsFeed).toHaveBeenCalled();

  // THis method will clear the successful subscription scenario
});


it("component #newsFeedServiceSubscribe() method for failed subscription",() => {

  // This line will call the service and instead of returning mockData, it will fail it.
  spyOn(realService, 'yourMethodName').and.returnValue(throwError({status: 500}));
  
  // Rest is the same
  spyOn(component, "newsFeedServiceSubscribe").and.callThrough();
  component.newsFeedServiceSubscribe();
  expect(component.updateNewsFeed).toHaveBeenCalled();

  // THis method will clear the failed subscription scenario
});
```